# Simulate touch manipulation on Linux

Tags: testing, touch-screen, development, multi-touch

I'd like to test how well my Linux app works on Linux-based touch devices. Unfortunately, I don't have such a device, which is why I'd like to find a way to simulate touch gestures on a standard laptop.

Is there a way to do that? How?

Comment: Could this https://github.com/vi/virtual_touchscreen help ? (I never tested though)

Answer (score 1):

You should search for `uinput` and `evdev` with `evtest`. If you can get a list of touch
events from someone with a real device, using `evemu-record`, you can replay them with `evemu-play`. See
[Understanding
evdev](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/09/understanding-evdev.html) to see
how you can log absolute x and y events from a touchscreen device, such as `EV_ABS / ABS_X`, `EV_ABS / ABS_Y` and a touch such as `EV_KEY / BTN_TOOL_FINGER`.
You can put these in a file, edit them and add your own, and replay the result with `evemu-play`, or send one
event with `evemu-event`.
There are C and [Python](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
api's to create UInput devices and send events through them ([tutorial](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#injecting-input)).

This too-detailed
[pdf](https://mchehab.fedorapeople.org/kernel_docs_pdf/linux-input.pdf),
*The Linux input driver subsystem* may help you recognise some of the
events you need to emulate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sounds pretty complicated, we'll see if I get around to it.